# How can this normal table be modified to work properly with R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

I have a large table with different columns and some rows.
The columns represent different characteristics of each row. The row are my different items i would say.

The overall buildup or relevant columns are like so:

> ```
> ColumnID     Classification       will_use_b       Region 
> 1            A                    TRUE             A
> 2            A                    FALSE            X
> 3            B                    TRUE             X
> 4            C                    TRUE             A
> 5            D                    FALSE            A
> 6            A                    TRUE             A
> ```

The aim for me is for example to print barchart havin the column `Classification` at the x-axis and show the number of occurences on the y-axis. More, beforehand I wanted to filter that only items are used with the parameter `will_use_b` are `TRUE`.

WIth the current table format I don't get this to work for me, more I am not sure how to define these conditions with column `will_ues_b`

My first try was to make use of tibble from tidyverse:

```
df <- read.csv2("file.csv", header = TRUE)
data <- tibble(
  colID= df$ColumnID,
  class= df$Classification,
  willUse = df$will_use_b,
  reg= df$Region,
)
##and then
grouped <- data %>% 
  group_by(class) %>% mutate(classsum=sum(class))
```

But that does not work and I am not sure how to filter beforehand.
I was reading about the `gather()` function, could this help in my case?
The overall aim is just to have some kind of Barplot with the amount of each Classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  group_by(Classification) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(will_use_b)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(y=sum, x=Classification) + geom_col()
```

[image]

Comment: one quesion: when i want to filter for more values, for example this should only count these items with `will_use_b` and are region `A` can I just connect the `summarise` with another `summarise`?

Comment: @SRel You can add the condition in the same `summarise`, `summarise(sum = sum(will_use_b & Region == 'A'))`

Comment: thanks, however when I use the filter in sumamrise the bars are not plotted however thex still takes place and are just empty. how can i beforehand exclude those lines so that they are not plotted with value=zero?

Comment: @SRel If you need to remove rows with zero values. You just need to add `filter(sum != 0)` so try `df %>%
  group_by(Classification) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(will_use_b)) %>%
  filter(sum != 0) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(y=sum, x=Classification) + geom_col()`  Or `df %>%
  group_by(Classification) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(will_use_b & Region == 'A')) %>%
  filter(sum != 0) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(y=sum, x=Classification) + geom_col()
`

Comment: perfect thank you! is there also some easy command so hat the bars or the piechart is ordered based on the sum? in know the order command however I can only call this with columns, I am not sure how to integrate it into your command

Comment: I haven't really used pie charts but maybe you can try reorder factor levels of `Classification` based on their `sum`.